# Tkinter Radiobutton: Remove dot along with image

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ubuntu, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to run a Tkinter program on both Ubuntu and OSX.

For some reason `Radiobutton` on Ubuntu comes along with the default dot. I've used `Radiobutton` since I want only one of the buttons to get selected.

On Ubuntu16.04 it looks like:
[image: Ubuntu]

While on OSX it looks like:

[image]

Lines of relevant code:

```
arousalButton[i] = Radiobutton(arousalFrame, variable=arousalVar, value=i+1, image=arousalPhoto[i])
arousalButton.pack(side=LEFT)

valenceButton[i] = Radiobutton(valenceFrame, variable=valenceVar, value=i+1, image=valencePhoto[i])
valenceButton[i].pack(side=LEFT)
```

How can I get a similar looking GUI on OSX? Where dot is not present along with the image.

Also, why is image quality in Ubuntu way better than OSX (My mac has better monitor resolution)

Comment: Try setting `indicatoron=0` when creating the `Radiobutton`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Could you please write an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `indicatoron` to 0 when creating the `Radiobutton` can hide the dot, for example:

```
arousalButton[i] = Radiobutton(arousalFrame, ..., indicatoron=0)
```